# How do tags get associated badges?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags, badges

I have a general question about how topic tags become associated with a vote-based badge.  For instance, if I receive 100 upvotes on answers  for at least 20 non-community wiki answers with the associated the tag [astrophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophysics), then I get a bronze [astrophysics badge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/131/astrophysics?userid=59023).

In contrast, if I get (currently) 103 upvotes on 31 non-community answers associated with the [solar-wind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-wind) tag, I see no bronze badge.

How are tag badges created/formed for a given tag?

Answer (score 8):

[solar-wind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-wind) has 80 questions, and tag badges are only awarded for tags which are used on [100 or more questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/295232). Consequently, you also can't track a tag badge for [solar-wind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solar-wind) in your profile.

Comment: Ah okay, the requirement is a minimum of 100 questions then?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @honeste_vivere - looks like its time to ask 20 good questions on the solar wind!